# SSIS: What is the best way to convert data types when data source is SQL table?

Tags: ssis

I have just started using SSIS 2013. Whenever I try to flow data from SQL table to SSIS derived column I always gets an error.

I have a table with all columns as nvarchar data types. I need to convert the columns to nvarchar, integer, money, bool, and etc.

**Edited**:

Basically I have realised that though SSIS and SQL are both Microsoft product but the data types in SSIS and SQL are not named same.

The following links has details of mapping of SSIS data types to SQL data types:[SSIS to SQL Server Data Type Translations](http://bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1387/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific transformation to match your need - Data Conversion.

As a quick intro I suggest you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I9IfZUK2dk and do some minor googling to come back with more specific questions.